# jQuery not updating span

Tags: jquery, html

I'm pulling my hair out here using jQuery to update a span contents, but it's just not working!

http://jsfiddle.net/PottyMonster/34mGm/

I've included everything below, even though i'm sure it's only this that isn't working:

```
$("#YouGet").html(StringToGoIn);
```

--- Html ---

```
&pound;<input onChange="CutCalculator();" id="CostField" type="text" class="ItemFieldCost" name="Cost" value="100" />
<span id=\"YouGet\">&pound;50.00</span>
```

--Script in Header ---

```
    function IsNumeric(strString)
//  check for valid numeric strings    
{
    var strValidChars = "0123456789.-";
    var strChar;
    var blnResult = true;

    if (strString.length === 0) {
        return false;
    }

    //  test strString consists of valid characters listed above
    for (i = 0; i < strString.length && blnResult === true; i++) {
        strChar = strString.charAt(i);
        if (strValidChars.indexOf(strChar) == -1) {
            blnResult = false;
        }
    }
    return blnResult;
}



function CutCalculator() {

    var Value = $('#CostField').val();

    if (IsNumeric(Value) === false) {
        alert("You didn't enter a valid value");
    }
    else {

        Value = parseFloat(Value);

        var Split = 0.5;
        var SupplierGets = Value * Split;
        var StringToGoIn = "&pound;" + SupplierGets;

        // alert(StringToGoIn );   <--- works fine
        // ---- WHY IS THIS NOT WORKING?!?! - URGH!!!
        $("#YouGet").html(StringToGoIn);

    }

}
```

Also, just out of interest, I've recently seen many people doing jQuery selectors like...

```
$('span[id=YouGet]').html(data);
```

Instead of

```
$("span#YouGet").html(StringToGoIn);
```

is there any reason for this?

Comment: Any reason why your quotes in the HTML are escaped? That's probably causing the problem. Also, it's better to use `$('#YouGet')` than any of the above options, since IDs are unique so the span part is irrelevant.

Comment: Box9 is correct.  Your code works once the slashes are removed.

Comment: @Box9, you should make your comment into an answer as it is in fact the issue, http://jsfiddle.net/9Ddv6/

Comment: @Serge, Thanks for confirming. As for making an answer, I'll let one of the correct answers below get the rep ;)

Comment: Thanks guys, I feel like a total idiot now,lol. It's part of a PHP script thus the escaping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're escaping the quote characters in your ID name. Thus, the id of your span is `"YouGet"`, not `YouGet`. Remove the escaping from the quotes in the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Take away the escapes `id="YouGet"` works

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/mzm6g/

This seems to work.